# Code seen instead of Relationships 5.67.0 and 5.67.1

Tags: relationships, formbuilder

When viewing or editing contacts in 5.67.0 or 5.67.1, I see the following instead of the relationships that have been assigned:

```
{{:: ts('Permissioned Relationships:') }}  {{:: ts('This contact can be viewed by the other.') }}  {{:: ts('This contact can be viewed and edited by the other.') }}
```

Reports does show the proper relationships, so the table information is correct.

How can I restore the capability to add and change relationships?

EDIT: In response to Coleman. Here is the console:

```
administrator/:29 [Deprecation] The keyword 'searchfield-cancel-button' specified to an 'appearance' property is not standardized. It will be removed in the future.
jquery-migrate.min.js?7ff9af6c210154c3364bf0718cadd787:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
angular.js:15697 Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$compile/multidir?p0=afFieldset&p1=%20(module%3A%20af)&p2=afFieldset&p3=%20(module%3A%20af)&p4='afFieldset'%20controller&p5=%3Cdiv%20af-fieldset%3D%22%22%20api-entities%3D%22%5B'RelationshipCache'%2C%20'Contact%20AS%20RelationshipCache_Contact_far_contact_id_01'%5D%22%3E
    at angular.js:99:1
    at ba (angular.js:11088:15)
    at aa (angular.js:10338:11)
    at Xa (angular.js:9865:15)
    at angular.js:11012:38
    at angular.js:18075:37
    at m.$digest (angular.js:19242:15)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:19630:13)
    at k (angular.js:13473:36)
    at v (angular.js:13730:7)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:15697
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11956
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11047
(anonymous) @ angular.js:18075
$digest @ angular.js:19242
$apply @ angular.js:19630
k @ angular.js:13473
v @ angular.js:13730
y.onload @ angular.js:13635
load (async)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13618
s @ angular.js:13418
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13159
(anonymous) @ angular.js:18075
$digest @ angular.js:19242
$apply @ angular.js:19630
(anonymous) @ angular.js:1966
invoke @ angular.js:5208
c @ angular.js:1964
Wc @ angular.js:1984
(anonymous) @ crm-angularjs-loader.js?r=lMhHken_US:7
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ crm-angularjs-loader.js?r=lMhHken_US:6
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ Common.js?r=lMhHken_US:1606
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
J @ jquery.min.js:2
angular.js:15697 Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$compile/multidir?p0=afFieldset&p1=%20(module%3A%20af)&p2=afFieldset&p3=%20(module%3A%20af)&p4='afFieldset'%20controller&p5=%3Cdiv%20af-fieldset%3D%22%22%20api-entities%3D%22%5B'Note'%2C%20'File%20AS%20Note_EntityFile_File_01'%2C%20'EntityFile%20AS%20Note_EntityFile_File_01'%2C%20'Note%20AS%20Note_Note_entity_id_01'%5D%22%3E
    at angular.js:99:1
    at ba (angular.js:11088:15)
    at aa (angular.js:10338:11)
    at Xa (angular.js:9865:15)
    at angular.js:11012:38
    at angular.js:18075:37
    at m.$digest (angular.js:19242:15)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:19630:13)
    at k (angular.js:13473:36)
    at v (angular.js:13730:7)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:15697
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11956
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11047
(anonymous) @ angular.js:18075
$digest @ angular.js:19242
$apply @ angular.js:19630
k @ angular.js:13473
v @ angular.js:13730
y.onload @ angular.js:13635
load (async)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13618
s @ angular.js:13418
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13159
(anonymous) @ angular.js:18075
$digest @ angular.js:19242
$apply @ angular.js:19630
(anonymous) @ angular.js:1966
invoke @ angular.js:5208
c @ angular.js:1964
Wc @ angular.js:1984
(anonymous) @ crm-angularjs-loader.js?r=lMhHken_US:7
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ crm-angularjs-loader.js?r=lMhHken_US:6
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
trigger @ jquery.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ Common.js?r=lMhHken_US:1606
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
J @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: Sounds like you have some type of javascript error on your site causing the page rendering to crash. Can you open up your browser console and update your question with the errors you are seeing there?

Answer (score 2):

After disabling all extensions that were not included in 5.67.0 or 5.67.1, I uninstalled, forcibly removed all related directories, and reinstalled 5.67.1. This worked.

Please note that the install was to be fresh but com_civicrm/admin/configure.php from the install directory detected an existing table in the schema and required an upgrade install, so I had to restore the settings files to complete the install.

- components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
- administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php.

After this, all seems well...

Comment: Thank you for your tips. Do you uninstall the whole CiviCRM component, through Joomla extensions manager ? And re-install it always through Joomla extensions manager ? (sorry, I cannot comment ?!?)

Comment: Uninstall as possible from Joomla then remove files/directories from command prompt. Once all the "junk" is gone, reinstall from Joomla.